# Compiling CUDA with clang

Tags: cuda, clang, llvm-clang

I am new to LLVM. I heard that clang supports CUDA. How do I compile CUDA using clang? Do I have to make some config changes or include any specific header files? I couldn't find any information on this on the web. Is it possible at all?

Right now when I try to compile a dummy cuda program with clang as

```
clang -I /usr/local/cuda/include filename.cu
```

I get the following error

```
 unknown type name '__global__'

 __global__ void nothing(int *A)
```

any help is appreciated! btw i am running it in a mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**2016-05-01 Update: clang now supports CUDA. See @rivanvx' answer.**

The CUDA compiler is based on LLVM. Clang, though also based on LLVM, does not support CUDA.

Comment: But then, how should I parse .cu file? No other tool?

Comment: @RogerDahl, you may want to update your post with the 3.8 version of CLANG that supports CUDA to a good extend.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to contributions from Google and others, Clang now supports building CUDA. Command line parameters are slightly different from `nvcc`, though. According to the [official documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html), assuming your file is named `axpy.cu`, the basic usage is:

```
$ clang++ axpy.cu -o axpy --cuda-gpu-arch=<GPU arch>  \
    -L<CUDA install path>/<lib64 or lib>              \
    -lcudart_static -ldl -lrt -pthread
```

Note that using Clang for compiling CUDA still requires that you have the proprietary CUDA runtime from the [NVIDIA CUDA toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit) installed.